# React / React-Native where to store dynamic refs with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

My app have got a lot of dynamic inputs which you can increment, remove and edit, problem is that before kill app I have to store current form state, values cannot be cleared.

Mapping values inside func component from a redux state slows down rendering because every render, refs are created again and current ref always equals null, using **useRef** with **createRefs** inside creates new issue because newly created inputs doesn't invoke newest references and rendering last input throws error.

Right now values are stored with redux persist, refs are stored in separated reducer named formRefs which is in blacklist in **redux-persist**.

I don't know if this may aggravate performance of redux. everything works but redux is overloaded when I'm opening redux devtools and it's crashing. Any one got similar issue? Any better solutions?

Comment: We have extremely complicated forms. But rather than handling all of it ourselves, we use a form library - tcomb-form-native. I am also not sure if using refs is a good idea, if all you want to do is store some form values to your reducer state - just use a plain old onChangeText/onChange handlers of the inputs and dispatch actions to store values to your reducer state. Start simple, you can complicate it later on.

Comment: references are required because I have got extended keyboard with arrows for navigation to upper and lower input and I have to use focus functions